# ''Error while connecting to MySQL Not enough parameters for the SQL statement'' Upsert python mysql

Tags: python, mysql, csv, upsert

I'm trying to perform Upsert query on csv dataframe in python mysql but getting error that
''Error while connecting to MySQL Not enough parameters for the SQL statement''
Here is my query:`

```
            for i, row in df1.iterrows():
            # sql = "INSERT INTO demodb.brand_publisher_level_magnitude_averaged_event_level VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
            sql = ("INSERT INTO demodb.brand_publisher_level_magnitude_averaged_event_level(content_id, "
                   "publisher_id, brand_id, curr_time, magnitude_signups_per_views_event_level_30_days, "
                   "magnitude_signups_per_views_event_level_90_days)"
                   " VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)  "
                   "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "
                   "content_id =%s, "
                   "publisher_id =%s,"
                   " brand_id =%s, "
                   "magnitude_signups_per_views_event_level_30_days  =%s, "
                   "magnitude_signups_per_views_event_level_90_days  =%s ;")
            cur.execute(sql, tuple(row))
            print("Record inserted")
```

Comment: What is the structure of `row`?

Comment: It's a CSV data frame row that has 5 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked for **six** parameters in your query (`content_id`, `publisher_id`, `brand_id`, `curr_time`, `magnitude_signups_per_views_event_level_30_days`, and `magnitude_signups_per_views_event_level_90_days`), but according to your comment, your CSV data only contains **five** columns. These become your sql parameters (thus, the error *Not enough parameters for the SQL statement*).

Either remove the missing column from the query, or (if it isn't nullable) set a default value in the `VALUES` statement. In short, your `VALUES( ... )` needs to match the number of fields in your `INSERT INTO table ( ... )` statement.